# Looking up Stock Symbols in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, finance

It has been a few years since i had used Mathematica, and I know that after yahoo feed was discontinued there have been some changes to how mathematica handles financial data. Back in the day we would go to yahoo finance and find the ticker symbol for a company and use that ticker in Mathematica. Such as `^N225`, however now this ticker is not showing. What can i do to lookup a ticker or find a company which company name. Is there a method which allows for this. Such as can I find `TSLA` by looking up Tesla?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

WL used to provide data for ^N225, it no longer does. The following indexes are currently available

```
FinancialData["Indices"]
```

Names of those indexes

```
AssociationMap[FinancialData[#, "Name"] &, FinancialData["Indices"]]
```

---

Here is a way using the company name

```
EntityValue[EntityClass["Company", {"Name" -> "Tesla"}], "CommonShares"] // Last // Map[Last]
(* {"NASDAQ:TSLA", "DE:TL0", "F:TL0"} *)
```

The correct company name has to be used

```
EntityValue[EntityClass["Company", {"Name" -> "Alphabet"}], "CommonShares"] // Last // Map[Last]
(* {"NASDAQ:GOOGL", "NASDAQ:GOOG", "DE:ABEA", "DE:ABEC", "F:ABEA", "F:ABEC"} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it was exactly what i was looking for. Could you please help me 1 more time. How can i find the symbol for ^N225 or Japanese Nikkei? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @Slartibartfast See updated answer.